# formula for multinomial expansion raised to three

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

who could kindly give me the formula for 
$$(x_1+x_2 + \cdots+ x_n) ^3,$$
in the form like the case
$$(x_1+x_2 + \cdots+ x_n) ^2 = \sum^n_{i=1} x_i^2 + 2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} x_ix_j.$$

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_i x_i^3+3\sum_{i\neq j}x_i^2 x_j+6\sum_{\substack{\{i,j,k\}\\i\neq j\neq k}}x_ix_jx_k$$

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I want

Comment: Though it's long time ago, but shouldn't $i \ne j $ and $i \ne j \ne k$ be "$ i < j$" and "$i < j <  k", respectively?

Comment: Again a long time but I think it should be $i \neq j$ and $i<j<k$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It was implicit in my mind. However, I prefer the way I've modified it, because it has the same form as the previous sum. Anyway, thank you for pointing it!