# Expansion of the cube of the sum of N numbers

Tags: polynomials, summation, cubics, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

I know that the expansion of the square of a summation can be expressed as:

$$\left( \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n^2 + 2 \sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} a_i a_j$$

where $a_n \in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ or $a_n \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ for $n=1,…,N$ (see for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187687/expansion-of-the-square-of-the-sum-of-n-numbers)).

This seems, of course, just a neat elegant formulate to facilitate the usage of the multinomial theorem for when exponent equals to $2$. I wonder if there is a similarly neat elegant formula for when the exponent is equal to $3$. Or, in other words, an analogous formula to expand $\left( \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right)^3$ that saves the time of having to resort to the multinomial theorem itself.

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394638/formula-for-multinomial-expansion-raised-to-three) in this website it is said that it would be something like:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^3+3\sum_{i\neq j}^Na_i^2 a_j+6\sum_{i\neq j\neq k}^Na_ia_ja_k$$

However, I agree with a comment there that has never been replied to. Shouldn't it be instead:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^3+3\sum_{i<j}^Na_i^2 a_j+6\sum_{i< j< k}^Na_ia_ja_k$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left( \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right)^3 = \sum_{i=1}^N a_i^3 + 3 \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_i^2 a_j+ 3 \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_i a_j^2+6 \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1} a_i a_j a_k$$

Comment: Ok, I think that expresses exactly the form that I came up with in the edit that I made to the question exactly while you were posting: $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n^3+3\sum_{i<j}^Na_i^2 a_j+6\sum_{i< j< k}^Na_ia_ja_k$. Thanks!

Comment: No, it's a little different i.e. the second term is different