# Expansion of the quartic of the sum of $N$ numbers

Tags: polynomials, summation, quartics

Can someone provide me the expansion for the following?

$$A=\left( \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right)^4 $$

I found square and cubic expansions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979925/expansion-of-the-cube-of-the-sum-of-n-numbers)

If there is any general expansion for power $k$

$$A=\left( \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \right)^k $$
Please provide too.

Answer (score 2):

This actually is related to [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):

In your case we have:
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}\right)^{k}=\sum_{t_{1}+...+t_{N}=k}^{ }{{k}\choose{t_1,..,t_N}}\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left(a_{n}\right)^{t_{n}}$$