# Sum of $n$ real numbers

Tags: real-numbers

It is quite well-known that

$(x_1 + \ldots + x_n)^2 = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i}x_ix_j$.

Is there a similarly elegant way to express
$(x_1 + \ldots +x_n)^4$?

Comment: Not as elegant, but the multinomial theorem does give an expression for this, yes.

Comment: Just apply the previous identity twice, even though it's not thaaat nice.

Comment: You want the second sum to be $j=1$ to $i-1$, not $i$.

Comment: The formula that you showed was derived by noticing that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2.$  The other formula may be similarly derived by noticing that $(a+b)^4 = a^4 + 4a^3b + 6a^2b^2 + 4ab^3 + b^4.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3532682/995003